# How can I convert empty images so that they would show in the render?

Tags: image

I've made a noob mistake and set up a whole scene with empty image objects.

Is it possible to convert them so they would show in the render? I know I can delete everything and start importing everything from scratch as planes, but that would take too much time to start all over again.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I don't think it's possible to convert them. However, you can add *images as planes*, and easily copy the location and rotation of the original empty image. I could post a full answer, if you're interested.

Comment: Yes! That would be great!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11):

DanielEngler has created [an add-on](https://github.com/danielenger/Empty-to-Image-Plane) to convert Image Empties into mesh objects.

After installing and activating the addon, simply select an Image Empty and click on the *"Add Image Planes"* button in the *Empty to Image Plane* tab of the sidebar in the 3D view.

[image: animated gif showing the usage of the addon]

[Related discussion on BA](https://blenderartists.org/t/convert-empty-to-an-image-2-79-2-8/1167182)

Comment: Sweet. Didn't know that. This should be the top answer :).

Comment: This is the best answer! and still works in blender 3.3.1 - thanks a lot