# Images as planes are not appearing in final render but in viewport are visible

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, image

I imported images as panes to create mist effect using PNG images. These are not appearing in the final render but are appearing in the viewport in render mode.

[image]

Comment: Link to the image
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11sllNa-BkFEZ-Od-tiV9eCP2c2h0CWh-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have you checked the render visibility in the Outliner?

Comment: Yes @moonboots, all are visible. I realised I might have dragged and dropped them in the viewport. These are appearing as Empty in the layer panels. Is there a way to convert them to image planes? Thank you! :)

Comment: so they are not Images as Planes but Reference or Background images, you need to reimport as Images as Planes, or create a plane and give it the image

Comment: Awesome, here's a link to a similar question. There's an add-on to convert reference images to planes. Thank you for the help @moonbots  :D https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161610/how-can-i-convert-empty-images-so-that-they-would-show-in-the-render

Comment: @Sherry1221 for future reference, any future new information, please add to the body of your question as an [edit]. Many users choose not to read the comments, and the comments are also not searchable and thus not useful for future visitors looking for an answer to their questions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

When you drag an image into the viewport, or use *Add* > *Image* > *Reference*, or *Add* > *Image* > *Background*, those images will have no real geometry (they are just an empty with an image associated to it), and as such they are not renderable. They are just reference.

Use *Add* > *Image* > ***Images as Planes*** (or File > Import > Images as planes) to have an object that has 4 vertices and a face with the image used as a texture on the material.